# What is the way to reach a field or a method of a far away base class in a double diamond?

Tags: c++, g++, multiple-inheritance

In the "classical" diamond problem like in the following
(one where there is no `virtual` in front of `public D`,
behind `class C` and `class B`), one may resolve the
ambiguity using the namescope operator `::`, such as in the constructor of class `A`:

```
/* 
 *   D                            D   D
 *  / \   which without 'virtual' |   |
 * B   C      is actually:        B   C
 *  \ /                            \ /
 *   A                              A
 */
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class D                      { public: char d = 'D';};
class C : public D           { public: char c = 'C';};
class B : public D           { public: char b = 'B';};
class A : public B, public C { public: char a = 'A'; A();};

A::A() {
    cout << B::d; //This works! B's d, inherited from D.
    cout << C::d; //This works! C's d, inherited from D.
    //cout << D::d;     //This doesn't work (ambiguous)
    //cout << B::D::d;  //Doesn't work either though.
    //cout << C::D::d;  //Doesn't work either though.
}

int main() {
    A a;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Consider a double diamond such as this now:

```
/* 
 *   G                          G  G G  G
 *  / \                         |  | |  |
 * E   F                        E  F E  F
 *  \ /                          \ / \ /
 *   D                            D   D
 *  / \   which without 'virtual' |   |
 * B   C      is actually:        B   C
 *  \ /                            \ /
 *   A                              A
 */
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class G                      { public: char g = 'G';};
class E : public G           { public: char e = 'E';};
class F : public G           { public: char f = 'F';};
class D : public E, public F { public: char d = 'D';};
class C : public D           { public: char c = 'C';};
class B : public D           { public: char b = 'B';};
class A : public B, public C { public: char a = 'A'; A();};

A::A() {
    cout << /* How do I reach any of the two e's or f's 
               or any of the four g's?*/
}

int main() {
    A a;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How exactly would one reach the fields inherited from E, F and G?
What actually seemed most logical to me was the following.

```
cout << B::D::d;
cout << B::D::E::e; 
cout << B::D::F::f; 
cout << B::D::E::G::g; 
cout << B::D::F::G::g; 

cout << C::D::d;
cout << C::D::E::e; 
cout << C::D::F::f; 
cout << C::D::E::G::g; 
cout << C::D::F::G::g;
```

However (using g++) they all yield an error of the form `'X' is an ambiguous base of 'A'.`.

Can somebody explain why this doesn't work and what's the proper way to do this? What am I missing?

Comment: I haven't fully hashed this out, but you could do this, as a starting point in `A::A()`, taking things one little step at a time: `B &b=*this;`. Now you have a `B`. Keep drilling...

Comment: I believe you had mistyped `cout << B::D::F::e;` instead of `cout << B::D::F::f;`.

Comment: Have you tried `dynamic_cast`

Comment: @ManthanTilva that can only be used with polymorphic objects

Comment: `dynamic_cast<G*>(dynamic_cast<E*>(dynamic_cast<D*>(dynamic_cast<B*>(this))))->g;`

Comment: @ManthanTilva will fail to compile, since the class is not polymorphic (try it if you don't believe it)

Comment: @M.M https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/BPRfkX It's working. Polymorphic is not strict requirement.  http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.dynamic.cast#1

Comment: @ManthanTilva oh, you are right. The rule says that dynamic_cast can be used for a non-polymorphic type so long as we are only casting from derived to base  (not from base to derived).

Comment: You likely meant `std::cout << B::D::F::f;` as well as `std::cout << C::D::F::f; ` as @ManthanTilva pointed out. This is working in MSVC++ (see my post below).

Comment: In g++ this will not work as per the reasoning mention by @M.M... Is there a reason you're not using the `virtual` keyword? This is a scenario it is intended to be used in and would allow the code to compile. I've updated my answer (initially intended for MSVC++) to use `virtual` as an alternative to M.M's answer in g++

Comment: Yea, I meant F::f and fixed that now. Also I can verify static_cast and dynamic_cast both work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work:

```
cout << B::D::d;
```

is because: the scope resolution is right-left associative; this is in a sense like `(B::D) :: d`, although parentheses aren't actually allowed here.   So the qualified lookup `B::D` is resolved, and that finds the type `D`. There's only one type called `D`  , there are not separate types `A::D` and `B::D`.  The same type can be found in multiple scopes.

Therefore you get the equivalent of `D::d` which is ambiguous since there are multiple paths to a base of type `D` .

---

To get at the variable you want, you may have to use a series of casts, e.g.:

```
cout << static_cast<G&>(static_cast<E&>(static_cast<D&>(static_cast<B&>(*this)))).g;
```

In C-style syntax you can use `((G&)(E&)(D&)(B&)(*this)).g` although that is dangerous as if you make a mistake in the class ordering you'll get a `reinterpret_cast` instead of a `static_cast` which can malfunction.

Actually in this case you can omit the `D` step, since a `B` has a unique `E` base:

```
cout << static_cast<G&>(static_cast<E&>(static_cast<B&>(*this))).g;
```

or even:

```
cout << static_cast<B&>(*this).E::g;
```

since there is a unique `E::g` once we are at `B`.

---

It is also possible to use `dynamic_cast` instead of `static_cast`, I'm open to comments about which one would be a better style :)

Comment: Just tested in a VM and indeed it doesn't work in g++. MSVC++ must have left-to-right scope resolution then.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the error you're getting. `'X' is an ambiguous base of 'A'.`

The compiler is telling you that there's an ambiguity/uncertainty in getting the parent of the object you've selected for std::cout. Without specifying abstract base classes, you're correct in the inheritance structure.

```
/* 
 *   G                          G  G G  G
 *  / \                         |  | |  |
 * E   F                        E  F E  F
 *  \ /                          \ / \ /
 *   D                            D   D
 *  / \   which without 'virtual' |   |
 * B   C      is actually:        B   C
 *  \ /                            \ /
 *   A                              A
 */
```

Now the problem is actually in what you're writing to standard out.
here's what you've written:

```
cout << B::D::d;
cout << B::D::E::e; 
cout << B::D::F::e;  // When does F inherit from E and get member variable e?
cout << B::D::E::G::g; 
cout << B::D::F::G::g; 

cout << C::D::d;
cout << C::D::E::e; 
cout << C::D::F::e; // When does F inherit from E???
cout << C::D::E::G::g; 
cout << C::D::F::G::g;
```

I have yet to test this with g++ (I'm using MSVC++), but this works:

```
A::A() {
    std::cout << B::b
              << B::D::d
              << B::D::E::e
              << B::D::F::f
              << B::D::E::G::g << std::endl;
    /* How do I reach any of the two e's or f's
               or any of the four g's?*/
}
```

Cheers!

Edit:
Here's the error you're facing in MSVC++
[image: Image describing compile time error of F trying to access member variable E... "ambiguous"]

Here's some proof of it working in MSVC++":
[image]

Now in g++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
class G                      { public: char g = 'G';};
class E : virtual public G           { public: char e = 'E';};
class F : virtual public G           { public: char f = 'F';};
class D : public E, public F { public: char d = 'D';};
class C : virtual public D           { public: char c = 'C';};
class B : virtual public D           { public: char b = 'B';};
class A : public B, public C { public: char a = 'A'; A();};

A::A() {
    std::cout << A::a
              << A::B::b
              << A::B::D::d
              << A::B::D::E::e
              << A::B::D::F::f
              << A::B::D::E::G::g 
              << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    A a;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Here's a link to the error page which may offer an alternative explanation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2385?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C2385)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019

Comment: what version of MSVC? They didn't start implementing proper name lookup until recently

Comment: This is VS 2019 (v142, or MSVC++ 14.23) using ISO C++17 Standard (std:c++17)